# Looking for alternate pants with 'snaps' around calf and/or shin area

Tags: clothes

Right now I have a pair of the prana Zion Stretch pants with these little 'snaps' around the area described in title. This allows you to basically roll up your pant leg(s) (ideal for moving out of the way of the chain) and 'snap' them into place. 'Snaps' being pairs of mating buttons closed by applying pressure.

I am looking for something similar, that is, something integrated into the pant itself, as opposed to a separate 'ankle collar' for any pants you like.

Comment: Why not DIY? I'm pretty sure those buttons you mentions are sold cheap at any sewing supply store...

Comment: You could always just tight roll your pants. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_rolled_pants

Comment: @jimirings that's essentially what i'm talking about actually, the zion pants i have are more designed to roll (I suppose you could do your best to 'fold' but that would take some time due to the elasticity of the fabric, and have almost no gain), then get stuck into place than 'fold up flat'. So basically, I want something (integrated) to keep them there once rolled. Also, that's funny, I remember that trend...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For next to nothing you can install snaps on any pair of pants you want:

[image: Snaps]

There are kits with anvils and presses and others with plier-type setting tools. Both work well and both are cheap. I'd suggest trying it out on a similar piece of material so that you can get a feel for how they work.

[Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004Y698) is a link for a cheap kit ($4.92 USD!)

If you're looking for more adjustability, you can sew velcro right into the cuff of your pants as well. (And while you're at it, you can buy reflective piping and reflective ribbon to increase your visibility.)